# Subtract dates in Linq EF6

Tags: linq, entity-framework, date

Hello i have big problem with Subtract at Linq,EF6.
I have date where repair should be finieshed. I woluld like to count how many days left.

At ViewModel I have:

```
public TimeSpan TimeToLeft{get;set;}
```

At repair controler i do sth like this:

```
var repairsToDo = from r in db.Repairs
join c in db.Car on r.Car equals c.ID_Car
join m in db.Models on c.ID_Modelu equals m.ID_Modelu
join b in db.Brand on m.ID_Brand equals b.Brand
where r.Data_Zakonczenia>=DateTime.Today 
select new RepairsToDo { TimeToLeft=(r.EndDate-DateTime.Today) };
```

View:

```
<table class="ShowDataTab">
        <tr>
            <th>Repair Number</th>
            <th>Car</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Desc</th>
            <th>Time to left</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model) { 
            <tr>
                <td>@item.FixNumber</td>
                <td>@item.Brand@item.Model</td>
                <td>@item.FixName</td>
                <td>@item.FixDesc</td>
                <td>@item.TimeToLeft</td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

And i got error like this:

```
dbarithmeticexpression arguments must have a numeric common type
```

How can i Fix it?

---

EDIT1:

Controler:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
                var repairsToDo = from r in db.Repair
                                  join c in db.Car on r.Car equals c.ID_Car
                                  join m in db.Models on c.ID_Model equals m.ID_Model
                                  join b in db.Brand on m.ID_Brand equals b.ID_Brand
                                  where r.EndTime>=DateTime.Today
                                  select new { ... EndTime=r.EndTime };

                var model = repairsToDo.AsEnumerable().Select(raw => new RepairsToDo {...   TimeLeft= raw.EndTime- today });

return View(model);
```

Error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[<>f__AnonymousType1a`7[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.DateTime],Praca_Inzynierska.Models.RepairsToDo]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Praca_Inzynierska.Models.RepairsToDo]'.
    enter code here
```

Comment: Ok, this is not very clear. Where do you get this error?

Comment: When i run application and try use this View.

Comment: I think you should add the respective portion of your `View` on your post.

Comment: What type is `Data_Zakonczenia`

Comment: Data_Zakonczenia = EndOfTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably simplest to just fetch the data from EF, and then perform the arithmetic locally:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var rawData = from r in db.Repairs
              join c in db.Car on r.Car equals c.ID_Car
              join m in db.Models on c.ID_Modelu equals m.ID_Modelu
              join b in db.Brand on m.ID_Brand equals b.Brand
              where r.Data_Zakonczenia >= DateTime.Today 
              select new { ..., r.EndDate };

var model = rawData.AsEnumerable() // Perform the select locally
                   .Select(raw => new RepairsToDo {
                               ... // other properties
                               TimeToLeft = raw.EndDate - today
                           });
```

Note that I've fetched `DateTime.Today` *once*, rather than doing it multiple times - that way you'll get a consistent result, even if this query is performed around midnight.

I'd also recommend renaming `TimeToLeft` as `TimeLeft` or `RemainingTime`.

Comment: I like the fact you added `var today` makes more sense to not calculated in each iteration. Wouldn't `raw.EndDate - today` result to a timespan? OP requests for days, so you could wrap it in parenthesis and get the `Days` portion, no?

Comment: Yes it is TimeSpan because this is the result of subtract two dates.
But what I need is only a number for example 2,5 etc.

Comment: @AdamLato: Then why do you have a `TimeSpan` property? You can always take the `Days` or `TotalDays` property from the `TimeSpan` if you want... but you need to make your model properties have the types that you actually want...

Comment: I tried:
TimeToLeft= r.Data_Zakonczenia.Subtract(DateTime.Today).Days and at ModelView i Have public int TimeToLeft{ get; set; }
But i got error: Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @AdamLato: You won't get that error if you perform the projection in LINQ to Objects, as per my answer. If you update your question to change the property type, I'll update my answer...

Comment: I created DateTime.Today as a object but i still get this same error. I tried method what You show (@Jon Skeet), but i still get error that model want only RepairToDo model ,but i deliver two: 1 anonymousand 2 RepairToDo

Comment: @AdamLato I didn't follow that at all, I'm afraid. It's hard to give a complete answer when we don't have all the context...

Comment: @Jon Skeet please look at first post.

Comment: @AdamLato: That doesn't really help, as I don't know what you mean by "delivering two models". Why isn't everything you need in the RepairToDo model?

Comment: @Jon Skeet  I paste error what I got. View expect 1 model. But when i assign RepairToDo to model, it see 2 models at one.

Comment: @AdamLato: Well the code I put in my answer doesn't create an anonymous type for the model - it creates an `IEnumerable<RepairToDo>`. I don't know what code you've *actually* got, but it looks like you're creating an anonymous type where you shouldn't be.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet THANK YOU! I had IQueryable... Thank You again for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
TimeToLeft = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("DAY", r.EndDate, DateTime.Now)
```

Change DAY for whatever unit you want. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487052(v=vs.110).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx.

Comment: Visual don't know what is it Objects at   System.Data.Objects.SqlClient

Comment: @AdamLato: Your comment doesn't make a lot of sense, but do you have a reference to `System.Data.Entity.dll`?

Comment: I can only add System.Data.Entity, i don't have dll option.
But when i try write SqlFunctions... visual don't know this method.

Comment: Well you'd need a `using` directive for `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient` as well... which version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 1):

With EF6 use

```
System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.DiffHours(time1,time2).Value
```

for example:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
...
entity.tableData.Select(m => new 
               {
                   m.Key,
                   horasTotales = m.Sum(h => DbFunctions.DiffHours(h.fecha_fin, h.fecha_inicio).Value)
               })
```